# Setting a default value in views jump menu d7

Tags: views, routes

I followed a tutorial on how to use the jump menu functionality in views drupal 7 link http://dev.nodeone.se/node/771,it was successful.
i have one problem though,I need to show a default value(for example a taxonomy term by default) if nothing is selected instead of the  drupal default to -select- . 
i have opened the file in views/plugins/views_plugin_style_jump_menu.inc and found this code,it looks like here is where i am supposed to change. but i just dont understand this code. Any help will be appreciated

```
 
function option_definition() {
    $options = parent::option_definition();
    $options['hide'] = array('default' => FALSE);
    $options['path'] = array('default' => '');
    $options['text'] = array('default' => 'Go', 'translatable' => TRUE);
    $options['choose'] = array('default' => '- Choose -', 'translatable' => TRUE);
    $options['default_value'] = array('default' => FALSE);

    return $options;
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, just went to views admin, deleted the -select-, reordered my taxonomy terms and bum!! it worked! am so dumb.